# Firefox DNS resolution order

Tags: firefox, dns, hosts, mdns

Do you know what is the DNS resolution process order of domain names in Firefox?

Has the hosts file proprity over DNS server?
Has the hosts file proprity over mDNS names in the network or mDNS is completely ignored?

Thanks.

Comment: In... which operating system? Linux? macOS? FreeBSD? Windows?

Comment: I guessed Firefox solves names in a platform-indipendend way, if it is not, I'm interested in Windows and Linux

Comment: While browsers are indeed somewhat more involved in the name resolution process than a typical app, they _still_ rely on the OS-provided services that all other apps use. Firefox certainly doesn't bundle a mDNS or NBNS implementation, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Almost universally on all operating systems, the resolve order is as follows :

1. Check if the name queried is our own.
2. Search the local Hosts file
3. Search the Domain Name System (DNS) server
4. Windows might continue to do NetBIOS name resolution, with similar actions on other OS.

Comment: Does not it seach with multicast?

Comment: Some do query in parallel multiple network adapters, if they exist. Apart from that, only one DNS server is contacted at any one time on a given network adapter.

Comment: I meant multicast-DNS, I'm triyng to point firefox the specific local server using a webapp name, but I cannot set records or change the DNS server in the network. For example http://mywebapppage for now I'm usign hosts file in every computer in the network but it is not very handy in case of DHCP network. I know that zeroconfig or mdns was made for something like this

Comment: You may assign the DNS server computer a static IP, but ensure that the DHCP allocation range does not include it.

Comment: I'm not the sysadmin of the networks, i cannot use dns resolution... as I said, I cannot set records or change the DNS server in the network. This is a distributed software that should works in the local network using browsers, but I canno ask to change dns, many times dns is the dns of the internet provider.

Comment: If the computer has a name inside the local network, it should be findable by some form of my 4th point.

Comment: @Tobia: Both mDNS and NetBIOS (NBNS) have to be provided by the OS – Firefox doesn't bundle its own implementation.

Comment: Ok, let's say my OS has mDNS. How shoud I publish the service name _http._tcp?

Comment: @Tobia: Firefox won't do SRV or DNS-SD service lookup at all. It _only_ performs direct "hostname ⇒ address" (e.g. "foo.local") resolution.

Comment: I don't know the Mac - on Windows this is a parameter of the IPv4 settings. HTTP, TCP aren't used for DNS queries.

Comment: I think some NAS devices (Synology) with web-interface control resolved this problem in some-way without using Netbios or network dns. I could login just with `http://mynasname` and the only service I found is mdns... but maybe I'm missing something. I cannot understand if is there a tool or some way to know the name resolution source (hosts/dns server/mdns ...) of a query name.

Comment: There's surely a way to achieve this. Without any knowledge of the Mac, perhaps [this link](https://frankl.in/code/setup-local-dns-resolver-on-macos-sierra) might be useful.